# C# behavior of "Duplications" of props

Tags: c#, properties, interface

Well, assuming I have 2 interfaces IBook, IJournal
and each holds same properties besides one different enum, For instance:

```
public interface IBook
{
    //each Book Must have these parameters.
    BookCategory BookType { get; set; }
    string ItemName { get; set; }
    DateTime Time { get; set; }
    int Copynumber { get; set; }
}
public interface IJournal
{

    JournalCategory JournalType { get; set; }
    string ItemName { get; set; }
    DateTime Time { get; set; }
    int Copynumber { get; set; }
}
```

and a Class named AbstractItem use them both: class AbstractItem : Ibook, IJournal
What will happen?
Am I going to have:

```
BookCategory BookType { get; set; }
JournalCategory JournalType { get; set; }
string ItemName { get; set; }
DateTime Time { get; set; }
int Copynumber { get; set; }
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's exactly what you will have.  Have you not tried it?

Comment: No, since it that would actually happen and i will figure it by myself i will have a doubt about how things were going.

Comment: @N3wbie, in programming, things either work or they don't.  It's nice to get reassurance from others but in the time it took you to ask this question you could have created a test class implementing these interfaces to see what would happen.  Are you more likely to remember that something works based on what someone else said or the fact you know it works because you have done it yourself?

Comment: Actually I'm new to C# so I prefer being alittle bit more cautious. Anyway thx man